# Terraform workspace in TFE?

Tags: terraform

I'm demoing the SaaS offering of TFE and getting an error running my plans.

```
Error: module.vpc.var.database_subnets: key "default" does not exist in map var.vpc_CIDR in:

${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_CIDR[terraform.workspace],4,6)}
```

Vars file looks like this

```
variable "vpc_CIDR" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    "dev"  = "10.92.64.0/19"
    "prod" = "10.92.32.0/19"
  }
}
```

What gives? The "Workspace" listed in TFE doesn't map to `terraform.workspace`? I can't set my `terraform workspace` anywhere that I can tell... This is a huge problem for normal TFE workflows.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with TFE. As a workaround, I created a variable named `env` which I set to `dev` or `prod` in the corresponding Terraform workspace:

```
${cidrsubnet(lookup(var.vpc_CIDR,var.env),4,6)}
```

Comment: no official guidance from hashi on this without breaking normal tf usage? Seems like a big oversight